# Codeigniter required error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

The CodeIgniter framework constantly generates an validation required error even if the field is required (in "form_phone_data" method).
Value in the "user_id" field loaded with AJAX.

After clicking on the submit form button, a message is displayed that the "phone" field is not filled. If you remove the "required" from the validation parameters, an infinite page load appears (sending the form).

Code:

```
<?php
defined("BASEPATH") OR exit("Access denied.");

class Sup extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->app->user != FALSE){
            echo $this->app->tpl('Ошибка доступа','access_denied');
            exit;
        }
    }

    function signup_form()
    {
        $phone_signup = $this->security->xss_clean($this->session->userdata("phone_signup"));
        $this->app->header_file = 'signup';
        if(!empty($phone_signup)){
            $user = $this->app->get_user($phone_signup, 'phone');
            if($user && $user['firstname'] == 'none'){
                $this->form_user_data();
            }else{
                $this->session->set_userdata("phone_signup", NULL);
                echo "sss";
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            $this->form_phone_data();
        }
    }

    function form_phone_data()
    {
        $this->fv->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">','</div>');
        $this->fv->set_rules('phone','Номер телефона','trim|required|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|xss_clean|callback__scode');
        $this->fv->set_rules('verify_code','Код подтверждения','trim|required|numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[6]|xss_clean');
        $this->fv->set_rules('user_id','Системное поле','trim|required|numeric|xss_clean');
        if($this->fv->run() == FALSE){
            echo $this->app->tpl('Регистрация','signup/phone');
        }else{
            header("Location: ".URI."signup");
            exit;
        }
    }

    function send_phone_sms($phone)
    {
        $phone = $this->security->xss_clean($phone);
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10,10}+$/", $phone)){
            echo '<div class="error">Номер телефона должен быть в 10-значном формате, например 9098087766</div>';
        }else{
            $phone = "8".$phone;
            $sql = $this->app->get_user($phone, 'phone');
            if($sql){
                if($sql['firstname'] == 'none'){
                    ?>
                    <script>
                    $(".next").hide();
                    $("input[name=verify_code]").css("display","block");
                    $("input[name=user_id]").val(<?=$sql['id'];?>);
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    echo '<div class="inform">Код для подтверждения номера был отправлен Вам ранее. Пожалуйста, введите тот код, который мы Вам отправляли.</div><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Продолжить"/>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="error">На данный номер телефона уже регистрировались ранее. Введите другой номер и нажмите <b>Далее</b></div>';
                }
            }else{
                $phone_code = rand(100000,999999);
                $data = array('firstname'=>'none','lastname'=>'none','last_online'=>SERVER_TIME,'signup_date'=>SERVER_TIME,'photo_cover'=>'none','password'=>'none','phone'=>$phone,'verify_code'=>$phone_code);
                $this->db->insert('users', $data);
                $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                ?>
                <script>
                $(".next").hide();
                $(".next").hide();
                $("input[name=verify_code]").css("display","block");
                $("input[name=user_id]").val(<?=$insert_id;?>);
                </script>
                <?php

                // тут отправляем смс с кодом

                echo '<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Продолжить"/>';
            }
        }
    }

    function code($phone)
    {
        $phone = $this->security->xss_clean($phone);
        $code = $this->security->xss_clean(set_value('verify_code'));
        $user_id = $this->security->xss_clean(set_value('user_id'));
        $phone = "8".$phone;
        $sql = $this->app->get_user(array('id'=>$user_id, 'phone'=>$phone, 'verify_code'=>$code));
        if(!$sql){
            $this->fv->set_message('_scode','Неверный код подтверждения: '.$code.'');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            exit;
            $this->session->set_userdata("phone_signup", $sql['phone']);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    function form_user_data()
    {
        $user = $this->app->get_user($this->session->userdata("phone_signup"));
        $this->fv->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">','</div>');
        $this->fv->set_rules('firstname','Имя','trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->fv->set_rules('lastname','Фамилия','trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->fv->set_rules('password','Пароль от профиля','trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[36]|xss_clean');
        if($this->fv->run() == FALSE){
            echo $this->app->tpl('Завершение регистрации','signup/data', array('step'=>1));
        }else{
            $this->update_user_data($user['id']);
            echo $this->app->tpl('Завершение регистрации','signup/data', array('step'=>2));
        }
    }

    function update_user_data($user_id)
    {
        $data = $this->app->get_form(array('firstname','lastname','password'));
        $data['is_active'] = 1;
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id)->update('users', $data);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<script>
function phone_sms()
{
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php/signup/send_sms/"+phone,
        success: function(html){
            $("#phone_step").html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
<div class="padding">
    <center>
        <?=validation_errors();?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона"/>
            <a class="submit next" onclick="phone_sms();" id="ignore_dynamic">Продолжить</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id"/>
            <input type="number" name="verify_code" placeholder="Код подтверждения" style="display: none;"/>
            <div id="phone_step">
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: as a side note: don't use <center></center> anymore, its deprecated, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it should be `callback_code` instead of `callback_scode` on your phone rules

Comment: In controller function scode -> $this->sup->code($phone)

Comment: @S.Grig Well lets try this from a different approach then - you have callback__scode - so where is the method called _scode()? Note: You have two underscores instead of 1.

Comment: I have method _scode($phone) in the controller: function _scode($phone){ $this->sup->code($phone);}

Comment: I discovered the code you provide extending `CI_Model`, so is it a model or a controller?
 Can you show the `_scode` content?